# How to increase mask buffer and then offset it using r.mapcalc in GRASS?

Tags: grass-gis, landsat

I'm in the process of learning on how to remove clouds and cloud-shadows from Landsat images using GRASS. So far I was able to remove a lot of clouds from those images using `i.landsat.acca`, but it seems like they still require a lot of refinements:

[image: Removing Landsat 7 clouds]

I followed the GRASS manual for `i.landsat.acca` to obtain the image above: http://grass.osgeo.org/manuals/html70_user/i.landsat.acca.html.

Basically, the process is to run different Landsat band images for the same scene with `i.landsat.toar`, and then processed with `i.landsat.acca` to get the cloud areas. Then use the cloud area as a mask using `r.mapcalc`:

```
r.mapcalc "MASK = if(isnull(clouds))"
```

**Problem#1**: the cloud edges is still visible. I need to increase the cloud-mask buffer to catch those renegade cloud edges.

**Problem#2**: the cloud-shadows is still visible. If I include the `-s` flag to include a category for cloud-shadow when running `i.landsat.acca`, a large amounts of shadow from the terrain will consequently be removed as well... So to catch the cloud-shadows, I believe I need to make a new mask for them - by offsetting the current cloud mask until they cover the cloud-shadow areas.

To achieve both objectives, I believe I need to modify and play with the `r.mapcalc` command, but I can't figure out how to write it (due to my bad Math and my-even-worse programming skills)..

So, my ultimate question:

***Question#1***: How do I edit `r.map.calc` to increase the mask area (let's say by a buffer of 10 units)?
**Question#2**: How do we offset a mask in `r.map.calc` (in this case a little to the south-west direction)?

If I know the answer to both of these: I can combine both cloud-mask and cloud-shadow-mask, to get a relatively cloud-free image. Then it's a matter of overlaying it to images of the same scene of different dates.

I appreciate any help that I can get. Many thanks!

Comment: Did you look at http://grass.osgeo.org/manuals/html70_user/r.grow.distance.html?

Comment: Note that the amount of offset must depend on the altitudes of the clouds and the elevation of the terrain: it is not a simple lateral movement of the clouds to mask the shadows!

Comment: @markusN I'm not quite clear on the use of `r.grow.distance`.. Can we use it to offset stuff around? What should I use as the `distance` parameter?

Comment: @whuber I've looked around for methods to do this - one of them is http://www.fs.fed.us/global/iitf/pubs/iitf-gtr32.pdf.. They've stated that "the effects of Sun illumination angle, topography, and cloud elevation should be considered"; but they didn't exactly tell how they use these parameters.. Do you know any good documentation that explains this kind of operation?

Comment: @whuber Oh.. They've picked shadows located over low-elevation landscapes where clouds are at the greatest height above land, project the cloud mask over it and applied a 10px buffer to account for possible variations in the shadowed areas related to variation in cloud elevation and topography.. Now I need to learn how to actually move masks around using GRASS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @markusN and @whuber for pointing out some of my glaring oversight on my approach of dealing with this problem.

At first I thought what I needed was a mathematical `r.mapcalc` formula that could magically offset a mask around - which is the wrong thought-process. What I really need is to *first* apply specific raster commands to the cloud raster, and *then* include the processed raster in the `r.mapcalc` as a mask.

So, the answer to my problems:

**Problem#1: the cloud edges is still visible. I need to increase the cloud-mask buffer to catch those renegade cloud edges.**

**Solution**: Use the cloud-cover generated from i.landsat.acca and apply `r.buffer` or `r.grow` to it. For example:

```
r.buffer input=clouds output=clouds_buffered distances=30 unit=meters
```

**Problem#2: the cloud-shadows is still visible. If I include the -s flag to include a category for cloud-shadow when running i.landsat.acca, a large amounts of shadow from the terrain will consequently be removed as well... So to catch the cloud-shadows, I believe I need to make a new mask for them - by offsetting the current cloud mask until they cover the cloud-shadow areas.**

**Solution**: Duplicate the cloud-cover and offset it to its shadow using `r.region`:

```
r.region map=shadow n=n+100 e=e+100 w=w+100 s=s+100
```

or just by using 2-directions with `+` and `-` sign:

```
r.region map=shadow n=n-100 e=e+100
```

**The final mask**:

We can finally combine both cloud and cloud-shadow cover using `r.patch`:

```
r.patch input=clouds,shadow output=totalcloudcover
```

and then create a mask from that with `r.mapcalc`:

```
r.mapcalc "MASK = if(isnull(totalcloudcover))"
```

**Final thoughts**:

As @whuber pointed out, it's not as simple as reprojecting clouds around to mask its own shadow, because of the range of terrain, cloud-elevation and illumination angle effects.. The mask resulting from lateral movements overestimates all the areas with potential cloud shadows, and could include some underlying usable data - and should be further differentiated. At the very least, this technique is a start.

Comment: +1 This reply is exceptionally thoughtful and well reasoned.  Wonderful!